# How is home made yeast very approximately equivalent to?

Tags: yeast

https://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-8171553/Scientist-shares-home-yeast-recipe-people-moan-bake-bread.html

Of course it would depend on a lot of factors but how much dry yeast equivalent  would you say very approximately the above home yeast production recipe link would produce?
There is shortage of yeast in Japan (and in USA)- luckily we think we have sourced yeast from a shop.

Comment: That is just instructions for making a sourdough starter.

Comment: It's also the Daily Mail, which isn't renowned for accuracy even in simple, non-controversial topics, and always overcooks the headline